# What does it mean when a dictionary says something is "not a viable sentence"

Tags: american-english

I just want to know as to following.
"I am always doing" is not viable as a sentence.
What does this mean? 
Also, is this ridiculous sentence?

UPDATE:
Then what about this? What if someone asking me and he is always criticising everything I do, Are you still cutting the meat? Then yes! I'm doing. Is this wrong?

Comment: *Viable* there means "a sentence that makes sense *standing on its own*."

Comment: What does mean "standing on its own"?

Comment: It means, "not in the context of a preceding statement or question".  *Which do you prefer, red or blue? Blue.*  There, "blue" is a perfectly viable answer to the question, but standing alone, it is no more than a word.

Comment: @TRomano : Did you means it needs supplemant text?

Comment: The dictionary is wrong. The cited example may be somewhat unusual, but it certainly isn't "not viable". For example, [*At home, I am always on the move. **I am always doing.** I don't take the time to be. Time at home feels like such a precious commodity that I am parsimonious of it by doing two or three things at once.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=G-u4McT2CdYC&pg=PA149&dq=%22I+am+always+doing+I%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22I%20am%20always%20doing%20I%22&f=false) Nothing at all wrong with that - in fact, it's an example of what I would call ***good*** writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am doing* is not a complete sentence; we need to know what the speaker is doing before the sentence has sense and meaning.

Comment: First, I asked like this. What difference are these sentence.
I always do and I am always doing. The  someone told me that I can't use I am always doing.

Comment: I have confirmed that you cannot use *I am always doing* as a complete sentence.

Comment: Ah I missed it sorry. But is that having a meaning as itself? What if someone asking me, Are you still working? Then I'm doing. Is this wrong?

Comment: If you wanted to say that you're not a person to whom being idle comes easily, you can say "I'm always doing *something or other*."

Comment: @Carter. Yes, it is wrong. I told you in my answer that we need to know what the speaker is doing before the sentence has sense and meaning.

Comment: Then what about this? What if someone asking me and he is always criticising everything I do, Are you still cutting the meat? Then yes! I'm doing. Is this wrong?

Comment: *I'm always **doing***, with a strong emphasis to mark the unusual use, can mean *I'm never idle*. A once very famous poem exhorted readers "Let us, then, be up and doing,
   With a heart for any fate;
Still achieving, still pursuing,
   Learn to labor and to wait."

Comment: @Carter To "Are you still cutting the meat?" you answer *Yes, I am!* or *Yes, I still am* or *Yes, I'm still doing that*.

Comment: @StoneyB I think it's the contraction that's the problem. *Yes I 'am doing* seem marginally correct to me ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria Depends on how contemporary you wanna be. The first folio *Mac* has "like a rat without a tayle, Ile doe, Ile doe, and Ile doe".